# Why H2 database doesn't show my table in the browser

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I know H2 is an in-memory database and it exists as long as the application is running. I am following [this tutorial](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/h2-database-example/). It is working fine. But when I try to check my table in the browser while my app is running. But it doesn't show anything there. What is wrong? How can I check my table in the browser?

[image]

**Updated Info:-**

application.properties:-

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:C:/temp/test
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

# Enabling H2 Console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

# Custom H2 Console URL
spring.h2.console.path=/h2

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

#Turn Statistics on and log SQL stmts
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=false
#logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace
#logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=debug

logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
```

Main class:-

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: show your application properties and spring boot main class at least

Comment: It is as same as in the given tutorial link. Anyway, I add that info here again.

Comment: you have *schema.sql* in your resources folder with exact table name you are calling, right?

Comment: Yes, I have schema.sql with table name TBL_EMPLOYEES. So i am expecting to see a table with this name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The connection string that you're using to connect to your H2 database (`jdbc:h2:~/testdb`) seems to point to a different database from your connection string. You need to change the H2 console's connection string to match that. Click on the disconnect button and it should take you to a connection form. Enter your connection string in the JDBC URL field

Comment: yes, it was different in the property file. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Please correct your connection URL in properties file as below:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```